# TinyXML and preserving HTML Entities

Tags: c, xml, html-entities, tinyxml

I'm using TinyXml to parse some XML that has some HTML Entities embedded in text nodes. I realize that TinyXML is just an XML parser, so I don't expect or even want TinyXML to do anything to the entities. In fact I want it to leave them alone.

If I have some XML like this:

```
...
<blah>&uuml;</blah>
...
```

Calling Value() on the TiXmlText instance I get:

```
"uuml;"
```

So TinyXml always seems to remove the ampersand. Is there any way I can get it to leave it alone so it comes out unchanged?

Appreciate any ideas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [TinyXML documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html) you'll see that it recognizes only five character entities (`&uuml;` is not one of them), plus Unicode code point syntax `&#xA0;` or `&#160;`.

Comment: I see that, my problem is that it ruins entities it doesn't understand (by dropping the ampersand). I want it to simply pass through entities it doesn't understand.

Comment: I suspect that's a bug and you'll probably have to take it up with the author.  There's an email link on the main TinyXML web page.